# Echo Autor name or author id in Joomla 1.5

Tags: php, echo, author

I need name of author from article in Joomla 1.5 using php query

```
<?php echo $author ?>
```

For example here is my text

> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
>   ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
>   Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
>   ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

Author: `<?php echo $author_id or author_name ?>`

How I can get author name from php query? it is the shortest question

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$article =& JTable::getInstance('content');
$article->load(JRequest::getInt('id'));
$author = $article->created_by;
```